# filesystem is read-only .. possibly corrupted?

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install Ubuntu base(Ubuntu from scratch) but I have a problem...after the installation I get a system with read-only file system and also, /boot is not automounted.

here is my /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda1   /boot vfat defaults,noatime 0 2
/dev/sda2   /     ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1
```

here is how I chroot into the base system for installation:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
mount --types proc /proc /mnt/proc
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --make-rslave /mnt/sys
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --make-rslave /mnt/dev
test -L /dev/shm && rm /dev/shm && mkdir /dev/shm
mount --types tmpfs --options nosuid,nodev,noexec shm /dev/shm
chmod 1777 /dev/shm
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
source /etc/profile
export PS1="(chroot) ${PS1}"
<installation steps>
exit
cd
umount -l /mnt/dev{/shm,/pts,}
umount -R /mnt
reboot
```

when I run the following command the system becomes writable:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

what did I do wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what happens after you reboot? What gets printed on the console before you run the mount command?

Comment: I get kernel messages and then get a # prompt..

Comment: Most likely your installation steps are wrong.  A correct Ubuntu install shouldn't dump you directly into a root shell with a plain # prompt like that, even with a broken filesystem.  Sounds like you're getting /bin/sh for init instead of systemd.  You'll need to provide more details about your installation steps, or link to instructions that you followed.  Also, why are you installing into a chroot rather than using the Ubuntu installer?  Sounds like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Here is my installation steps: https://pastebin.com/GbwtEDsV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short Answer

In your installation steps, you need to install the `systemd-sysv` package.

#### Long Answer

Looks like you're installing Ubuntu Focal.  The Ubuntu Base image for Focal does not include a `/sbin/init`.  Assuming you're using systemd, which is the default, this binary is provided by the `systemd-sysv` package.  Note that the Ubuntu Base image for some earlier version of Ubuntu *do* include `/sbin/init`, so older instructions may not mention this.  (Why doesn't the image have `/sbin/init` anymore?  Probably because it's generally not needed in containers, which is an increasingly large use case of images like this.)

So how did you end up at a shell prompt without an init?  The `init` script in the `initrd`, which is responsible for `exec`ing a "real" init, has a fallback.  If `/sbin/init` isn't found, it tries a list of alternate executables, one of which is `/bin/sh`.  You probably also got a message like `Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init` printed to the console.

So how come your root filesystem was mounted read only?  Because that's what your GRUB config tells it to do.  Run `cat /proc/cmdline` and you should see that the `ro` option is included, which instructs the `initrd` to mount `/` read-only initially.  This allows init to, if necessary, run `fsck` to fix errors on your root filesystem.  Init will then remount `/` read-write.

Comment: Should I install systemd after installing grub+initramfs+kernel or before ?

Comment: I suspect the regular Ubuntu installer installs systemd-sysv first, so that probably what I'd choose.  But order probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, How do I change GRUB's config so that it wouldn't make the filesystem read-only ?

Comment: You don't need to make it mount read-write, systemd remounts it read-write for you.  If you really want to mount it read-write at boot, I suggest asking a new question.